# Items in the listview displayed only on end of translate-animation and not during the animation

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I have a simple layout - with a listview as shown.

[image: Overall layout]

The press of add icon at the top, triggers a simple translate-animation on the listview that moves it down by y-pixels, to reveal a form underneath. This part works fine - that is, the items in the listview move down out of screen along with the translate-animation, resulting in the screen shown below.

[image: Result of listview translate-animated y-pixels down, which works fine]

However, when the listview is translate-animated back up to its original position, it does not display all of its items during the slide-up animation. It displays its contents only after the end of the animation. Heres a screen-shot of the listview when the slide-up translate-animation is in progress. Notice the missing 3rd, 4th & 5th entries.

[image: Missing items during slide-up animation]

How do I ensure that the listview items are shown as and when they are supposed to become visible during the slide-up translate-animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. I had to use [ObjectAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) on the listview as recommended by [Google](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#object-animator). The problem with the previously used [TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html) was that the listview was not redrawn on layout change during the animation. With ObjectAnimator, each minor change in the Y-coordinate position of the listview during the animation, forces a redraw on the listview.

Comment: Any chance of some code here? I am having this same issue but my attempts to resolve the issue with an ObjectAnimator have not had a positive result at this point..

Comment: @ThomasClowes Thats going to take some time. Can post an example within a week or two... but by that time, I guess you would have gotten it right.